# How is session or variable state or object state maintained in a cluster ( Specifically for Java based app servers )?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, appserver

Suppose when my application is accessed through one of the nodes in a cluster and modifications are being made.Suddenly something happens to the node and taken over by another node in the cluster, will the transition happen correctly will anything be lost?

I do have seen some refernces but am still not clear how applications are maintained in a clustered environment?

Comment: What app-server / Web Container are you using?  Setup & how it works is dependent on the app server.

Comment: Glassfish with apache web server for load balancing

Answer (score 1):

Distributed Session Cache or storage can be used, like [Hazelcast one](http://www.hazelcast.com/documentation.jsp#HttpSessionClustering), which is compatible with Glassfish